# Link text files to all the cell rows depending on the value of column

Tags: excel

I have a folder (ABS) with an excel file that has details of lot of items.

One column has id's(col A) and others have some info like discription (colB) etc.

```
Column A      Column B     Column C
112           absads
123           asdasd
```

In the same folder I have txt files who's names are same as id's in col A.

I want the txt files in col C depending on the value in col A

Eg:- i have 112.txt and 123.txt files in the folder 'ABC' along with the above excel file.

What is the best way to get the text files in each column depending on the value in colA.

NOTE:- this example shows 2 files.... but i have like 2000+ id's and same number of text files. I dont want to do it manually :P

Please help

Comment: what exactly do you want in column C? the name of the text file? or the contents of the text file?

Comment: i want the content if possible.... else even link it to the file...so i can send the file to anyone and they can access it.

Comment: see the hyperlink function and to hyperlink to the file. for the content, you'll need VBA and if there's a lot of content, it will not fit in one cell.

Comment: Hyperlink is fine.... i can link it to the text file.. but for 2000+ entries how will VBA select which file to be linked to which cell ?

Comment: no vba needed. use the [`HYPERLINK` worksheet function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F). I was saying that you would need VBA if you wanted to put the content of the file into the cell.